# How to create an autoclik for a button? //JS

Tags: javascript, button

I have problems and doubts when doing an autoclik with a js button ... I tried everything

```
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1000);">
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("boton1")[0].click();
```

The id of the button is: boton1

but I still can't get it ... your help would help me a lot please, thank you

Comment: you should use `document.getElementById("boton1").click();`

Answer (score 2):

Hello you could try this out:

```
setTimeout(() =>
    document.getElementById("boton1").click()
, 1000)
```

If you want to set this timeout only when the page have started, this code should be wrapped in the "document.onready" call, just as the following way:

```
document.onready(() => {
    .
    . // Put the code above in here
    .
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is loaded before the event is fired.
Wrap your code for firing the event in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and wait for the DOM to be loaded. Then trigger the click. Also make sure your script is loaded in the `<head>` section of your HTML. Using a timeout to wait for the element is unsafe and could fail if your script was loaded "too fast".

```js
function doSomething(){
    alert("hi");
}
    
(function(){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        document.getElementById("boton1").click();
    });
})();
```

```html
<button id="boton1" onclick="doSomething()">
Click
</button>
```

Comment: ooh right, now I realized ... I had it behind the button, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cuentadeusa1993 Any time! Please consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML Code

```
<a id="boton1" href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

Javascript code

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('boton1').click();
}, 1000);
```